# How to iterate a map of string and structure in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, std

I am trying to iterate the below map and prints out everything in C++.

```
struct employee
{
    uint16_t id;
    uint8_t lastModifiedDate[8];
    std::string value;
};

std::map<std::string, employee> m1;
```

As you can see the above map is of type key string and value as employee...

Below is try I have given but somehow whenever I compile the above code, I get bunch of exceptions at my console.. I am not sure which error will make sense to copy paste it here... So that's why I am not pasting it here for now.. If somebody needs it, I can make it small and then copy it here..

```
std:map<std::string, employee>::const_iterator itMap = m1.begin();

for (;itMap !=m1.end(); ++itMap) {
    std::cout << itMap->first << " : " << itMap->second << std::endl;
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

Any idea what wrong I am doing here?

**Update:-**

This is the error message I am seeing -

> error: no match for operator<< in std::operator<<
>    >((* & std::operator<< , std::allocator >((* & std::cout), (* &
>   itMap.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator->, employee> >()->std::pair, employee>::first))), ((const char*)" : ")) <<
>   itMap.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator->, employee> >()->std::pair, employee>::second

Comment: You should include the error!

Comment: Well at least post a **complete, minimal code** then so we can recapitulate the problem.

Comment: Do you have an overload of the operator<< for employee ? You might want to replace `itMap->second` with `itMap->second.value`

Comment: I think 
std:map<std::string, employee>::const_iterator itMap = m1.begin();
should be 
std:map<std::string, employee>::const_iterator itMap = m1.cbegin();

Comment: I have updated my question with the error message.. Sorry about that..

Comment: @AquaAsh: I think it should be just `for (auto const& pair : m1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::cout` won't know how to print your `employee` until you override `operator<<` for `employee` type. Like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const employee& e)
{
    os << e.id << lastModifiedDate[0] << value;
    rteurn os;
}
```

Comment: Where I should be using this piece of code? You are saying that I should not use map to retrieve the data? And I should just use the above code?

Comment: your `for loop` is fine, you just need to add this function declaration in your header and put function definition in .cpp file.

Comment: Don't modify the code that you have. Implement this code anywhere before calling `itMap->second`. For example, right beneath the `struct  employee`. Don't forget to `#include <iostream>` for `std::ostream`.

Comment: @billz: In your example why are you using lastModifiedDate[0] like this? As the size of lastModifiedDate is eight bytes in my example?

Comment: @SSH it's just sample, you need to output each of element if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which member of the `employee` that you want to output to `cout`

```
std:map<std::string, employee>::const_iterator itMap = m1.begin();

for (;itMap !=m1.end(); ++itMap) {
    std::cout << itMap->first << " : " << itMap->second.value << std::endl;
    //                                                 ^^^^^^
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```